# Why does grep treat asterisk so weirdly?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, escaping

The issue is described as follows.

```
# cat test
hello
fedora

# cat test | grep h*o
hello

# cat test | grep 'h*o'
hello
fedora

# cat test | grep "h*o"
hello
fedora
```

`grep h*o` works as expected, but **WHY** do `grep 'h*o'` and `grep "h*o"` get `fedora` which contains no letter `h`?

Comment: grep speaks regex, not glob-style patterns. `*` means a different thing in the different languages.

Comment: All 3 produce the same results for me. `*` means *any number of `h`* (including none) followed by an `o`. So your examples in quotes make sense. However, your first case with no quotes will cause the shell to match `h*o` to whatever is in your current directory as a file name and use that as the string to match. What other file names are in your current directory? I don't have a file in my current directory matching `h*o`, so it works fine.

Comment: Do you have a file named `hello` in the same directory? If so, part of the answer to this particular question is that, in your second example, `h*o` is getting expanded to `hello` by your shell *before* getting passed to `grep`, so `fedora` is not matched.

Comment: @leekaiinthesky, yes, i have a file named hello in the current directory.

Comment: To do what you (appear to) mean, you should use a quoted string so the shell doesn't expand it, and `.*` to match anything.  So `cat test | grep "h.*o"`